# How to know if a guest user is running the application - c#?

Tags: c#, user-accounts

I have a winForm application and I want to know of a guest user is running it. 
how can I know it by c# code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an optimized version of what Barry said.

```
   if (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsGuest)
   {
     //User is Guest
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsGuest == true)
   {
     //User is Guest
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

That would depend entirely on how your users are setup.
You could use group membership to determine if a user is a Guest or they might be using the Guest account (although some organisations might disable that one).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Domain Auth? 
If you are using Domain Auth, get the current user details with

```
Environment.UserName or Enviroenment.UserDomainName;
```

and check if user is a member or not.