# WindowsIdentitiy.IsGuest doesn't work on .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, user-accounts

I'm trying discover if a user is a guest in windows7/windows8 using c# and .NET 3.5.

I've followed the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140002/how-to-know-if-a-guest-user-is-running-the-application-c) and tried calling [WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsGuest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.isguest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but it didn't work returns false also on guest account (on windows7 and on windows8).

I printed the WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value, and WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name and both are correct:

WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name  = ComputerName\Guest

WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value = S-1-5-21/Domain/501

when compiling the executable to .NET 4.5,  WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsGuest returned true on guest account (and false otherwize).

According to msdn documentation IsGuest should work on both .net 3.5 and 4.5.
Is there something I missing?

Is there another way to know if a user is guest?

**UPDATE:**

the following code works:

```
  public static bool IsGuest
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                if (identity == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var pricipal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
                return pricipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Guest);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, they indeed do it differently.  4.5 checks if the account is a member of the Guests group, 3.5 checks if the account is the Guest user account.  Which is where I run out of gas, your info says it is.  Other than the oddness of "Domain" showing up in the User.Value.  Make sure the account is a machine account and not a domain account.  The proper SID for the Guest account is S-1-5-21-32-501.

A possible workaround is to do it the same way that 4.5 does, check if the account is in the Guests group.

Comment: Why is it weird that the domain is showing up in the User.Value? according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330 the sid of guest account is S-1-5-21domain-501. Are you saying that the check in 3.5 is incorrect?

Comment: "domain" is a number.  It also doesn't have / slashes.  What does it *really* say?

Comment: I am sorry, the slashes were by mistake. what I meant to say is that the format was wxactly as it appears in support.microsoft.com/kb/243330. the sid was S-1-5-21-someNumber-501

Comment: I'll pull that tooth one more time, what does it **really** say.  If "someNumber" is not 32 then it won't work, you are not using the machine's Guest account.

Comment: The number is a long number that I can't remember now, but it is defenitly not 32. So actually what you are saying is that the 3.5 version of IsGuest checks only if the account is the machine's Guest account, and for some reason my guest account is not the machine's account?

Comment: Quote: `Make sure the account is a machine account and not a domain account`.  It is domain account.

Comment: I guess so :) but how can it be? I just turned on the guest account on windows and use it - isn't it the machine guest account?